# How do you get the keys from a transient map in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to get the seq of all of the keys in a transient map:

`(keys {3 4 5 6 7 8})` gives `(3 5 7)`

as I expect but:

```
(keys (transient {3 4 5 6 7 8}))
```

gives

```
#<CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap$TransientArrayMap (NO_SOURCE_FILE:346)>
```

on the same note, how do I process using a transient map?

```
(map identity {3 4 5 6})
```

gives

```
([3 4] [5 6])
```

but

```
(map identity (transient {3 4 5 6}))
```

gives

```
#<IllegalArgumentException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap$TransientArrayMap>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't really possible because of the interaction between laziness and mutability. `(keys m)` always returns a lazy sequence backed by the immutable `m` data structure, computing elements as necessary. But if `m` is a transient, it might change at any time, which would ruin the lazy key-sequence. You're really meant to not do anything too fancy with transients; and because it's so cheap to create transient or persistent versions of a data structure, it's not too onerous to go back and forth a few times if you really want to do something fancy.

Comment: I'll go with this for the moment. It seems as if transient map is only really good for `assoc!`, `conj!` and that type of operation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to work on transients like you work on persistent structures. You need to create a persistent structure from your transients with `persistence!`

```
user> (map identity (persistent! (transient {3 4 5 6})))
([3 4] [5 6])
```

You can learn more about transients from [Clojure docs](http://clojure.org/transients).